# Multer Does not upload files

Tags: javascript, angular, multer

So what i am doing here is

1.Upload file using filrreader and save blob as string in array

```
const reader=new FileReader()
reader.readAsDataURL(file)
```

2.pass the array to service

```
this.postService.onAddPost(
this.form.value.title,
this.form.value.content,
this.imagesObject
)
```

3.in service append it in formdata

```
    onAddPost(title:string,content:string,imagesObject:Array<string>){
        const postData=new FormData()
        postData.append("title",title)
        postData.append("content",content)
        for (var i = 0; i < imagesObject.length; i++) {
            // postData.append("images",imagesObject[i])
            postData.append("images",imagesObject[i])
        }
postData.forEach((value, key) => {
            console.log(key, value);
        })
        this.http.post<{message:string,postId:String}>('http://localhost:3000/api/posts',postData)
```

4.at post express backend trying to save in multer

```
var upload=multer({storage:storage})
router.post('',upload.fields([{name:'images'}]),(req,res,next)=>{
    const post= new Post({
        title:req.body.title,
        content:req.body.content
    })
    post.save().then(createdPost=>
        res.status(200).json({
            message:'Post added sucessfully',
            postId:createdPost._id,

        })
    )
})
```

by this the multer should upload the files.
I don't know what i am doing wrong?
Thanks
link to complete project on github 
[Project Link](https://github.com/ruinedmaniac/MeanStackSandBox)

[Chrome network->formadata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwB8f.png)

Comment: could you please show the filepath where you are mentioning it?

Comment: const storage=multer.diskStorage({
    destination:(req,file,callback)=>{
        const isValid=MIME_TYPE_MAP[file.mimetype]
        let error=new Error('Invalid mine type')
        if(isValid){
            error=null
        }
        callback(error,"backend/images")
    },
    filename:(req,file,callback)=>{
        const name=file.originalname.toLowerCase().split(' ').join('-')
        const ext=MIME_TYPE_MAP[file.mimetype]
        callback(null,name+'-'+Date.now()+'.'+ext)
    }
})

Comment: Please refer to the documents on Multer - https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer

Comment: this link also might help?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56243533/multer-stop-file-uploading-if-form-validation-fails/56335666#56335666